# Web SQL query not returning same number of rows as SQL Enterprise Manager query

Tags: internationalization

I've got a brain teaser I'm trying to figure out. My web page issues a query to a local SQL database and returns 2 rows. The problem is that when I copy and paste the exact same query directly into SQL Enterprise Manager, it (correctly) returns 3 rows!
My question is - how can the web version of the query only return 2 of the rows. 
Some background - the table being read contains varchar fields with english words and a nvarchar field which holds the Chinese equivalent. The code I use to perform the query is common code from a library I've used for years so I don't think it's necessarily the code being used to perform the query.

Here is the code from my webpage that loads the records. Right at the point where the recordset is initially loaded, I examine the rowcount from the recordset and it returns a value of 1 (which is zero-based, so there are 2 records in the recordset).

=================================================================

```
public function LoadByQuery(ByVal sQueryType, ByVal sQueryValue, ByVal sSortOrder, ByVal sDatabase)
    if IsOnErrorResumeNextActive() then on error resume next
        LoadByQuery=false

    mytrace("LoadByQuery")

    ' free any existing elements
    Cleanup()
    'dbconnfix
    'dim sSQL,rsSQL
    dim SQLConn,sSQL,rsSQL,sDSN
    dim arrData,nMarketingColCount,nMarketingRowCount,x,bRet

    nMarketingColCount=-1
    nMarketingRowCount=-1

    select case sQueryType
        case MARKETINGMGR_PARMTYPE_BYCLAUSE _
                    sSQL = "SELECT id,guid,store,customerid,employeeid,filetype," & _
                                   "creationdate,filename,filesite,filesize,friendlyname,md5hash,folder,description,descriptionchinese,brand,brandchinese,productid,views,siteuploaded,approved,tags,tagschinese " & _
                   "FROM " & MARKETING_TABLE_NAME & " "
           if sQueryValue<>"" then sSQL = sSQL & " WHERE " & sQueryValue
           if sSortOrder<>"" then sSQL = sSQL & " ORDER BY " & sSortOrder
        case MARKETINGMGR_PARMTYPE_BYQUERY sSQL = sQueryValue
        case else _
            sLastErrorMsg="Error: invalid sQueryType passed to LoadByQuery: " & sQueryType
            mytrace(sLastErrorMsg)
            exit function
    end select

    err.clear
    'dbconnfix
    ' Create the ADO objects
    Set SQLConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    ' fetch the connection string to the SQL database
    select case lcase(sDatabase)
        case POWERMAX_DATABASE
            sDSN=GetPowerMaxDSNString()
        case else
            response.write("ERROR: Database not specied in CMarketingMgr::LoadByQuery")
            response.end
    end select

    ' Open the SQL database
    SQLConn.Open sDSN
    if Err.Number <> 0 then
        sLastErrorMsg = "Error opening SQL Connection using DSN " ' & sDSN & " Err.Number = " & CStrIfNull(Err.Number) & " Err.Description = " & Err.Description
        mytrace(sLastErrorMsg)
        set SQLConn=nothing
        exit function
    end if

    Set rsSQL = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    mytrace(sSQL)

    rsSQL.Open sSQL,SQLConn
    ' able to open the recordset?
    if err.number<>0 then 
        sLastErrorMsg="Error: Unable to open recordset " & err.brand
        mytrace(sLastErrorMsg)
        exit function
    else
        if rsSQL.EOF=false then 
            ' items found: GetRows, and get row and column counts
            arrData = rsSQL.GetRows()
            nMarketingColCount=ubound(arrData,1)
            nMarketingRowCount=ubound(arrData,2)

        end if ' if rsSQL.EOF
    end if ' if err.number<>0

    rsSQL.close
    set rsSQL=nothing
    'dbconnfix
    SQLConn.close
    set SQLConn=nothing

    dim y

    ' customerid,employeeid, emailaddress, password
    ' Create new items from db
    dim s_id                        ' id of the db record
    dim s_guid
    dim s_store
    dim s_customerid                        ' Marketing customerid
    dim s_employeeid
    dim s_filetype
    dim s_creationdate          
    dim s_filename          
    dim s_filesite          
    dim s_filesize          
    dim s_friendlyname          
    dim s_md5hash           
    dim s_folder            
    dim s_description           
    dim s_descriptionchinese            
    dim s_brand         
    dim s_brandchinese          
    dim s_productid 
    dim s_views         
    dim s_siteuploaded          
    dim s_approved          
    dim s_tags  
    dim s_tagschinese   

    dim arr,sDate,sTime

    mytrace("nMarketingRowCount=" & nMarketingRowCount)
    ' Create new items and add to our array
    if nMarketingRowCount <>-1 then 
        ' for each record, add to our internal table
        for x = 0 to nMarketingRowCount
        ' add to internal table

            y=0

            ' globals
            s_id                        = CStrZeroIfNull(arrData(y,x)) : y=y+1 
            s_guid                      = CStrIfNull(arrData(y,x)) : y=y+1
            s_store                     = CStrIfNull(arrData(y,x)) : y=y+1
            s_customerid                = CStrZeroIfNull(arrData(y,x)) : y=y+1
            s_employeeid                = CStrZeroIfNull(arrData(y,x)) : y=y+1
            s_filetype                  = CStrIfNull(arrData(y,x)) : y=y+1
            s_creationdate              = CStrIfNull(arrData(y,x)) : y = y + 1 
            s_filename                  = CStrIfNull(arrData(y,x)) : y = y + 1 
            s_filesite                  = CStrIfNull(arrData(y,x)) : y = y + 1 
            s_filesize                  = CStrZeroIfNull(arrData(y,x)) : y = y + 1 
            s_friendlyname              = CStrIfNull(arrData(y,x)) : y = y + 1 
            s_md5hash                   = CStrIfNull(arrData(y,x)) : y = y + 1 
            s_folder                    = CStrIfNull(arrData(y,x)) : y = y + 1 
            s_description               = CStrIfNull(arrData(y,x)) : y = y + 1 
            s_descriptionchinese        = CStrIfNull(arrData(y,x)) : y = y + 1 
            s_brand                     = CStrIfNull(arrData(y,x)) : y = y + 1 
            s_brandchinese              = CStrIfNull(arrData(y,x)) : y = y + 1 
            s_productid                 = CStrZeroIfNull(arrData(y,x)) : y = y + 1 
            s_views                     = CStrZeroIfNull(arrData(y,x)) : y = y + 1 
            s_siteuploaded              = CStrIfNull(arrData(y,x)) : y = y + 1 
            s_approved                  = SetDefaultBitValue(arrData(y,x)) : y = y + 1 
            s_tags                      = CStrIfNull(arrData(y,x)) : y = y + 1 
            s_tagschinese               = CStrIfNull(arrData(y,x)) : y = y + 1 

            '-----------------------------------------------
            mytrace("s_creationdate: " & s_creationdate)
            arr = split(s_creationdate," ")
            sDate = arr(0)
            sTime="00:00:00" : if ubound(arr)>0 then sTime = arr(1)
            if isnumeric(Right(sDate,4)) then sDate = ConvertMMDDYYYYToYYYYMMDD(sDate)
            s_creationdate = sDate & " " & sTime
            mytrace("s_creationdate: " & s_creationdate)

            ' add the item to the array
            mytrace("AddToMarketingArray: id=" & s_id)
            if AddToMarketingArray(s_id,s_guid,s_store,s_customerid,s_employeeid,s_filetype,_
                s_creationdate,s_filename,s_filesite,s_filesize,s_friendlyname,s_md5hash,s_folder,s_description,s_descriptionchinese,s_brand,s_brandchinese,s_productid,_
                s_views,s_siteuploaded,s_approved,s_tags,s_tagschinese)=false then
                exit function
            end if

        next
    end if ' if nMarketingRowCount <>-1 

    LoadByQuery=true


end function
```

=================================================================
Here is the actual query that I copied and pasted from the display of the query on the webpage directly into SQL Enterprise Manager:

```
SELECT id,guid,store,customerid,employeeid,filetype,creationdate,filename,filesite,filesize,friendlyname,md5hash,folder,description,descriptionchinese,brand,brandchinese,productid,views,siteuploaded,approved,tags,tagschinese FROM MarketingCenter WHERE approved=1 AND filetype=N'C' AND (brand='Aveeno' OR brandchinese=N'艾维诺') ORDER BY filetype
```

The website recordset only contained 2 rows, but the Enterprise Manager query returned 3 rows. The website version of the query did not include the record that had the brandchinese set to N'艾维诺' whereas the Enterprise Manager query did.

I thought it might have something to do with the page header info, but the page displays Chinese characters just fine. Here is the header on my page:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CodePage = 65001%>
<%
Option Explicit
Session.CodePage = 65001
Response.charset ="utf-8"
Session.LCID     = 1033 'en-US
%>
```

Any thoughts as to why a record with Chinese characters in it would not be returned in my webpage invoked recordset even though Enterprise Manager returns the record from the same query?

Comment: I've just discovered that if I hard code the Chinese characters into the SQL Query, I get all 3 rows returned to me in my web page. The problem therefore seems to be in the way that my webpage reads the Chinese characters from the URL. In a prior page, I call my query page by passing the Chinese characters via the URL using the Server.URLEncode() function. That page I make the call from also has the same header with the CodePage=65001 and charset utf-8 so I am at a loss as to why passing the Chinese in this way results in a broken query...

Comment: Thanks, it looks like it's been removed.

Answer (score 0):

OK, not sure this really "answers" the question - but I found that passing the Chinese characters to another page via Server.URLEncode somehow altered the Chinese characters when read in by the target page and subsequently used in a SQL Query. 
By passing the Chinese characters to the target page by simply appending them to the URL (without using Server.URLEncode), the target page read the Chinese chars correctly and when used in a SQL Query, returned the expected rows. 
This is the first time I've ever encountered such a thing and I would be curious as to why this happens, but for now, the workaround for me was to REMOVE the Server.URLEncode from the Chinese characters when building the hyperlink.